# Site doesn't redirect properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a strawpoll website (bit like strawpoll.me but you can set the poll to expire and it uses cookies) which can be found at http://www.makepoll.co.uk.

The problem is that, when you go to it, we get bounced to http://www.makepoll.co.uk/1 when it should take you to http://www.makepoll.co.uk/home.

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([A-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

and my index.php page looks like this:

```
<?php require("backend/index.php");
if(empty($page)==TRUE)
{
    header("Location: home");
    die();
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php if(empty($part)==FALSE)
{
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"../frontend/jquery-ui.css\">\n";
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"../frontend/styles.css\">\n";
    echo "<script src=\"../frontend/jquery.js\"></script>\n";
    echo "<script src=\"../frontend/jquery-ui.js\"></script>\n";
}
else
{
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"frontend/jquery-ui.css\">\n";
    echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"frontend/styles.css\">\n";
    echo "<script src=\"frontend/jquery.js\"></script>\n";
    echo "<script src=\"frontend/jquery-ui.js\"></script>\n";
}
?>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php if(empty($part)==FALSE)
{
    echo "<a href=\"#content\" tabindex=\"", $tab++, "\"><img src=\"../frontend/content.png\" alt=\"Skip to Content\"></a>\n";
}
else
{        
    echo "<a href=\"#content\" tabindex=\"", $tab++, "\"><img src=\"frontend/content.png\" alt=\"Skip to Content\"></a>\n";
}
?>
<div id="pollbox">
<?php if(in_array("{$page}.php", $content)==TRUE)
{
    include("{$basedir}/content/{$page}.php");
}
else
{
    echo "<p>Page not found, I'm sorry</p>";
    http_response_code(404);
}
?>
</div>
<footer>
<ul>
<li><a href="../home/1" tabindex="<?php echo $tab++; ?>">Create New Poll</a></li>
<li><a href="../terms/1" tabindex="<?php echo $tab++; ?>">Terms of Service</a></li>
<li><a href="../terms/2" tabindex="<?php echo $tab++; ?>">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The backend/index.php page looks like:

```
<?php /* This file will contain the backend functions and set things up, such as the MySQL connection, and set the variables the site is going to use. This file line will connect to the SQL database. If there is a connection error, the script will be killed, and since there is no point continuing, a message will be displayed */
ob_start();

session_start();
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "example");
if($connection->connect_error)
{
    die("Sorry... I was unable to connect");
}
$basedir             = dirname(__FILE__);                         // This variable will hold the path to the current folder
$page                = strtolower($_GET["p"]);                    // This variable will hold the current page name
$part                 = $_GET["s"];                             // This variable will keep track of which part of the script the user is on
$tab                 = 1;                                                     // This variable will hold the tabindex
$content            = scandir("{$basedir}\content");        // This will scan the content folder and return an array 
unset($content[0], $content[1]);                                // This will unset the 0th and 1st element of the array 
include("{$basedir}/functions.php");                        // This will include the backend functions script
?>
```

Can you folks give me some pointers? As far as I'm concerned, it should redirect to /home

Comment: You should change the database connection parameters in `backend/index.php`

Answer (score 1):

Add this rewrite rule to the list

`RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/home$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can fix this problem using the absolute path to home with / at the end. Like this:

header('location: http://www.makepoll.co.uk/home/');

I didn't understand why there is a 1 appended to your url, though.

Also, you need to refactor your code and rethink about your architectue, but it is another question).